# How do you say "come a long way" in one word?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm writing a technical paper and need to say something along these lines:

> The technology in this area has come a long way in the past twenty years...

But I think "come a long way" doesn't seem as descriptive, and was hoping there is a better word for it.

Comment: OP should perhaps stick to his original *come a long way*. All posted answers are metaphoric usages based on "growth/expansion", rather than "advancement". OP's original metaphor more strongly implies that *much has been achieved*, whereas the "growth" metaphors have more the sense that *much effort has been made*, which isn't really the same thing.

Comment: "progressed greatly" ?  Two words, but --

Comment: How about **advanced**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually use the word [boom](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/boom).

> Boom: to grow, develop, or progress rapidly.

Comment: This is exactly what I need - Applying it to my sentence, which would be the appropriate usage: "This technology has been booming over the past twenty years" or "This technology boomed over the past twenty years"?

Comment: @nickb The former sounds better to me.

Answer (score 5):

Try *skyrocketed* if you want one word alone. Or, to convey the same effect, try *improved a lot*.

Comment: Using *improved a lot* seems even less imaginative to me than *come a long way*...but I like *skyrocketed* in the proper context, it comes with an attached intensity.

Answer (score 2):

"Matured" could be another option.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Answers at StackExchange are expected to be definitive; your submission could be improved by explaining *why* you suggest this option, including examples, dictionary definitions, and/or links to other references.  I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Progressed. As in, the technology progressed rapidly, from punch cards to keyboards to mice.

Comment: Be careful not to conflate, however, the *rate* of progress with the *magnitude* of progress.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. Answers are best when citations are provided. That keeps answers from being  simply opinion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think *burgeoned* is a reasonable fit.

Comment: *Burgeoned* might be a highly descriptive word but doesn't seem to improve the message when it comes to technology. *burgeon* is used more often with something that "blossoms" rather than "improve rapidly".  Technology doesn't really "blossom" or "flourish", but it's purely connotative.

Comment: @Rant dictionary.com has: "1.
to grow or develop quickly; flourish" I still feel it is a reasonable fit, as stated above, though not ideal.  Personally I am not fond of "boomed" here either; to my mind it speaks more of size and activity, rather than progress.

Answer (score -1):

*eclipsed*

If you really want to send the message that the technology has become much better, like night-and-day, then use the word eclipsed.

But if you want to be more descriptive, normally you would want to use multiple words, such as "improved by leaps and bounds".